# Reading input from the console in F#

Tags: functional-programming, f#

In the process of learning F#, I wrote this code that reads lines of input from the console and stores them in a list.

As far as I can tell the code works correctly, but since I'm new to functional programming, I'm not sure if it is written as well as it could have been.

1. Should I have read characters iteratively instead of recursively?
2. Is there a better alternative to using a `StringBuilder` object?
3. Does my code follow proper functional style?

```
open System

/// Appends a character to the string builder and returns the new builder.
/// Characters 10 and 13 (newline and carriage return) are ignored.
/// Returns the updated StringBuilder.
let appendChar char (builder : Text.StringBuilder) =
    match char with
    | 10 | 13 -> builder
    | n ->
        let c = Convert.ToChar(n)
        builder.Append(c)

/// Finishes building a string by clearing the StringBuilder
/// and appending the string to the end of the list of strings.
/// Empty strings are ignored.
/// Returns a tuple containing the lines and the new StringBuilder.
let finishString lines (builder : Text.StringBuilder) = 
    let s = builder.ToString()
    let l = builder.Length
    let newBuilder = builder.Clear()
    match l with
    | 0 -> (lines, newBuilder)
    | _ -> (lines @ [s], newBuilder)

/// Handles a character by appending it to the builder and taking an appropriate action.
/// If char is a newline, finish the string.
/// Returns a tuple containing lines and the new builder.
let handleChar char lines builder =
    let newBuilder = appendChar char builder
    match char with
    | 10 -> finishString lines newBuilder
    | c -> (lines, newBuilder)

/// Gets all the lines from standard input until end of input (Ctrl-Z).
/// Empty lines are ignored.
/// Returns a list of strings read.
let rec getLines lines builder =
    match Console.Read() with
    | -1 -> lines
    | c ->
        let tuple = handleChar c lines builder
        let newLines = fst tuple
        let newbuilder = snd tuple
        getLines newLines newbuilder

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    Text.StringBuilder()
    |> getLines []
    |> ... and so on
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some small comments

```
    let tuple = handleChar c lines builder
    let newLines = fst tuple
    let newbuilder = snd tuple
    getLines newLines newbuilder
```

can become

```
    let newlines,newbuilder = handleChar c lines builder
    getLines newLines newbuilder
```

although, if you aren't using `getLines` anywhere else, there is a good argument for making it

```
handleChar c lines builder |> getLines
```

by makeing `getLines` take its argument in tupled form.

The magic number 10 appears a few times, so I would add a literal like

```
[<Literal>]
let newline = 10
```

and then you can pattern match against it.

Also,

```
Lines @ [s]
```

is bad as `@` is very slow.  You are better to use

```
s::Lines
```

and then reverse the list at the end.

Your format for reading the characters recursively should be fine as it will get optimised as a tail-call.

Of course, your entire program could be replaced by:

```
let rec procinput lines= 
    match Console.ReadLine() with
    | null -> List.rev lines
    | "" -> procinput lines
    | s -> procinput (s::lines)
```

Comment: Is the order of the cases in `match Console.ReadLine() with …` important? I would guess no, but having them as `s`, `""` and `null` seems to time out a lot more often than `null`, `""`, `s`.